# Java.lang.ClassCastException: nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.xml.KonfettiView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

I'm going to use the konfetti effect on Android. However, while activity is loading views,
This error occurs when xml is loaded.

-------java code-------

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_achievement); // error occured!!!
    dialog.show();

    final KonfettiView konfettiView = (KonfettiView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.viewKonfetti);
konfettiView.build()
.addColors(Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA)
.setDirection(0.0, 359.0)
.setSpeed(1f, 5f)
.setFadeOutEnabled(true)
.setTimeToLive(2000L)
.addShapes(new Shape.Rectangle(5))
.addSizes(new Size(12, 5))
.setPosition(-50f, konfettiView.getWidth() + 50f, -50f, -50f)
.streamFor(300, 5000L);
```

---

-------xml code-------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    <nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView <!-- error occured!!! ->
        android:id="@+id/viewKonfetti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_achievement_dialog"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
Java.lang.ClassCastException:
    nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.xml.KonfettiView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

This means that you tried to convert `KonfettiView` into a `ViewGroup` on this line:

```java
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_achievement);
```

`KonfettiView` DOESN'T implement/extend a layout that does the same with the `ViewGroup` class.

This also means that your XML is wrong; it's not a layout, it's a plain ordinary view.

Which means it should look like this instead:

```xml
<nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.KonfettiView
    android:id="@+id/viewKonfetti"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

---

## But DO NOT Worry! There's A Workaround:

---

Simply make `nl.dionsegijn.konfetti.xml.KonfettiView` extend a layout.

In your case, make it extend a `LinearLayout` like so:

```java
//...
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
//...
public class KonfettiView extends LinearLayout{
//...
}
//...
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that orientation was a function only supported by the view group
I am also grateful to you for reminding me that I can use that function if I extend layout.

Comment: @user19632259 you are very much welcome! If this answer is helpful, please click on the check mark near my answer, much appreciated. Have a good day!